# what's the difference between .ivy2 and .m2

Tags: gradle

Previously I am using sbt, and looks like it put jar under .ivy2. And then I used gradle, I have thought it also put jar under .ivy2, but the following link told me I need to delete corrupted package from .m2. So gridle is using .m2 and can not use ivy2?
[spring boot mvc: failed after following the sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105619/spring-boot-mvc-failed-after-following-the-sample)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ivy, Maven and Gradle each have their own dependency cache in `~/.ivy2/cache`, `~/.m2/repository`, and `~/.gradle/caches`, respectively. Gradle will only use Maven's dependency cache (known as the local Maven repository) if `mavenLocal()` is declared as a repository in the build script. This should only be done if the Gradle build needs to consume artifacts produced by a local Maven build. (There aren't any efficiency gains; in fact declaring `mavenLocal()` will make the build slower and less reliable.)