# Server does not starts with spring app

Tags: eclipse, spring, apache, hibernate, tomcat

Getting this error message while trying to run Spring temple project do not know why ? any suggestions ?

Here is the full log from console

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_04\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\eclipse;;.
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 566 ms
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
Aug 12, 2015 4:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@6bef53]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4832)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4962)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@46128d]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:95)
    ... 13 more

Aug 12, 2015 4:46:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
```

I  have done any modification on code just trying to run app downloaded from spring template

Comment: This log output doesn't say anything relevant and it is quite certainly not the real problem. So either post the whole log output or look for a better part.

Comment: see the  edited log now @dunni

Comment: @BaluC did you see that this question was asked before that one? how can you mark this is as duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a jar file is corrupt. Can you try downloading it once more and trying?

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
```

is thrown because the server is not able to process the jar file.

Try removing the contents of your local maven repository and then run maven once more.

Comment: Its worked for me ..  spring roo was corrupted I removed that and cleaned the project again @rest_day

Answer (score 6):

Follow the Steps:

Step 1:Delete all the Content in .m2/repository Folder.

Step 2:Restart Your Eclipse.

Step 3:Maven->Update Project .Checked- Force Update of Snapshots/Releases.

Step 4:Run as  Maven Clean.

Step 5:Run as Maven Install.

Step 6: Clean Project.

Step 7 : Run Your Project.

I Hope you Find your Solution Here..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to guess looking at the available log, but one common problem I have seen people facing is, a port, like 8080, being occupied by something else. Restarting Eclipse, or restarting the PC at the worst, mostly fixes this.

**Update**:

Looking at the updated log, I recall facing the same issue with some combination of dependencies and a specific version of spring-boot-maven-plugin. To pin-point the issue, you can try changing the versions, removing foreign dependencies, etc. Searching for

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
```

Could help. Specifically, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105619/spring-boot-mvc-failed-after-following-the-sample) is of any help.

Comment: server has no issue  in running other apps  so its not port problem